# web.xml vs. annotation in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using Vaadin 7.4.3, tomcat 8.  During the wizard to create Vaadin 7 project in eclipse, it has a checkbox called "Generate web.xml deployment descriptor".

The new way is to use annotation instead of specify it in the web.xml.  Are there any configurations that I have to use web.xml because there's no annotation for it?  Is it a good practice to always generate the web.xml even if you might not use it for Vaadin 7.1 projects and up?

Thanks

Comment: One reason for a web.xml is to store configuration parameters and so on in the web.xml

Comment: @AndréSchild What do you mean with the configuration parameters?

Comment: For example this:     `<context-param>
        <description>Local cache node</description>
        <param-name>cacheNodeURL</param-name>
        <param-value>127.0.0.1:11211</param-value>
    </context-param>` or `<env-entry>
    <description>The LDAP Server to use</description>
    <env-entry-name>ldap.server</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>$ldapserver</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  </env-entry>` We use this to customize it depending on the environment and client instances

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are for sure some aspects of app that cannot be configured using annotations (i.e. there is no annotation to state that you want to have your session cookies "http-only" ).

I would recommend you to create web.xml file when it is needed. Sooner or later it would probably will be used, but don't worry too much in advance. It is not a dark magic to create web.xml file in existing project :)